# pytorch dataset map-style vs iterable-style

Tags: pytorch

A map-style dataset in Pytorch has the `__getitem__()` and `__len__()` and iterable-style datasets has `__iter__()` protocol. If we use map-style, we can access the data with `dataset[idx]` which is great, however with the iterable dataset we can't.

My question is why this distinction was necessary? What makes the data random read so expensive or even improbable?

Answer (score 16):

I wrote a short post on how to use PyTorch datasets, and the difference between map-style and iterable-style dataset.

In essence, you should use map-style datasets when possible. Map-style datasets give you their size ahead of time, are easier to shuffle, and allow for easy parallel loading.

It’s a common misconception that if your data doesn’t fit in memory, you have to use iterable-style dataset. That is not true. You can implement a map-style dataset such that it retrives data as needed.

Check out the full post [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20230628113759/https://yizhepku.github.io/2020/12/26/dataloader.html).

Answer (score 3):

It's quite possible that the full dataset doesn't fit in memory (could be on a disk, or only accessible over a network). A stream of information doesn't have to be retained if you're not going to access arbitrary offsets. If you're going to request data[0], then data[1], then data[2] over a network, you're sending a lot of requests which introduces latency.

Iterable-like (ResultSet) objects are typical when incrementally reading rows in the results of a database query. It's also conceivable that a dataset could inherently be a stream of information, like logging data, or transactions, or incrementally discovered pages found by a web crawler.